# how can i type message after submited in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
document.getElementById('form-giah').addEventListener('submit', message);

function message() {
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  if (title.value === '') {

    warning.innerHTML = ('عنوان الزامی است');
  }
};
```

```html
<form action="/save_giah" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-giah">
  <button type=submit>submit</button>
</form>
```

I want a message to appear on the page after submit,in javascript but unfortunately this message appears during loading and the message disappears after loading.
Please help me.

Comment: Hello! What have you tried already? Can you at least give us some trails you've followed? Some code example of what you tried? Thanks a lot! And welcome :)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to use PHP to provide a response. Or you can use Ajax to submit the form so that you can stay on the same page and show the message after the request has completed

Comment: Submitting the form will redirect to action page and you won't see the message you want to show. Use php to redirect back the page or use Ajax as ADyson said.

Answer (score 0):

Well if i understood you, you need to validate before it get's submited, so you can use it on the way bellow:

on form set `onsubmit="return message();"`

In the message you have to declare your variables, and make sure there will be no errors.
Then just `return false` if you wish to form not submit, and `return true` if you wish to form continue to submit data.

```js
function message() {
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  var warning = document.getElementById('warning');
  if (title.value === '') {

    warning.innerHTML = ('عنوان الزامی است');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

```css
input { display: block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="state" value="" />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" />
<form action="/#test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-giah" onsubmit="return message();">
  <button type=submit>submit</button>
  <p id="warning"></p>
</form>
```